# In MVC ,Html Kendo Grid is not passing "&" to the controller from view through Datasource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Kendo grid datasource is not passing values "&" from view to controller in MVC

For instance from the below code if testIdVal value is "Interface Class & Function" . Only "Interface Class" are being passed to the controller .

```
.DataSource(Function(d) d.Ajax() _
                                    .Read(Function(read) read.Action("GetResourcesForRolesForRootDomain", "Inquiry", New With {.testId= "#=testIdVal#"}).Type(HttpVerbs.Post).Data("additionalData"))) _
```

Comment: Two ideas on that one: Try to add `encodeURIComponent` around `testIdVal`: `"#=encodeURIComponent(testIdVal)#"`or add `testIdVal` in `additinaldata`. By the way, there is a typo in `additinaldata` ;)

Comment: Thanks  a lot Carsten , "#=encodeURIComponent(testIdVal)#" worked , Indeed additinaldata  was a typo :)  . You can put this in the answer list so that I will accept this as correct one .

Comment: the mentioned solution does not work for me. What am I missing?
this is what I have
Read(r => r.Action("GetGroupErrorData", "InventoryForecast", new { errorMessage = "#=encodeURIComponent(Message)#" }).Data("OnDetailDataBinding"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas on that one: Try to add `encodeURIComponent` around `testIdVal`: `"#=encodeURIComponent(testIdVal)#"` or add `testIdVal` in `additinaldata`. By the way, there is a typo in `additinaldata`. ;)