# Ajax call is not passing “&” to the controller from view through Url.Content

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, asp.net-ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Ajax call is not passing “&” to the controller from view through Url.Content

For instance from the below code if testIdVal value is "Interface Class & Function" . Only "Interface Class" is passed to the controller , "& Function" is ignored .

```
    $("#testdiv").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
        url: "@Url.Content("~/Customer/Test?Id=")" + testIdVal  + "&Flag=T"
    }).center().open();
```

Comment: Didn't you [already ask this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53363604/in-mvc-html-kendo-grid-is-not-passing-to-the-controller-from-view-through-d)?

Comment: Yes ,I already tried using encodeURIComponent(testIdVal) but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get an error message? What was it? What did the URL end up being when it didn't work?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response , there is no error . The url is taking & into account but when the debug point hits the action method the value "& Function" doesn't come .

Comment: You need to share code if you want help. What JavaScript and C# do you have now?

Answer (score 0):

`&` is used as a delimiter in a URL's query string. If you want to use the value `&` itself, you need to encode it.

```
// JavaScript:
encodeURIComponent("&");
// Output: %26
```

So you need to set `testIdVal` to "Interface Class %26 Function".

```
$("#testdiv").data("kendoWindow").refresh({
    url: "@Url.Content("~/Customer/Test?Id=")" + encodeURIComponent(testIdVal) + "&Flag=T"
}).center().open();
```

Query strings take the form of `?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=var3 ...`. Without encoding the ampersand, whatever's interpreting the URL will think you're trying to declare a new variable called "Function".